# error obtaining printer information VB6

Tags: windows, visual-basic-6, impressora

Quando vou realizar uma impressão através de um Data Report ao abrir a tela de impressoras do windows o seguinte erro ocorre: **error obtaining printer information**.
Alguma sugestão?

Comment: É uma impressora local ou remota?

Comment: Na verdade estou tentando enviar no PDF Creator, mas o erro ocorre ao carregar as impressoras do windows. Normalmente as impressoras são carregadas independentemente se vou usá-la ou não.